# Create function to handle and find data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Currently in my mapping (ES 6.2) i have two properties:

1. deadline: type date, store a datetime to know what is the
   deadline of a project
2. current_stats: type long, store if the
   status of a project is opened (1), closed (5) or canceled (4).

In my PostgreSQL I have a function that handles this data and returns whether the deadline was expired or not, like the code below:

```
IF (deadline IS NULL) THEN
--WITHOUT DEADLINE
RETURN 2;
ELSIF
(
((current_stats IN (4, 5)) AND (deadline >= current_timestamp))
)
THEN
--UNEXPIRED DEADLINE
RETURN 1;
ELSIF
(
((current_stats NOT IN (4, 5)) AND (deadline < datahora))
)
THEN
--EXPIRED DEADLINE
RETURN 0;
ELSIF
(
((current_stats IN (4, 5)) AND (deadline < current_timestamp))
)
THEN
--EXPIRED DEADLINE
RETURN 0;
ELSIF
(
((current_stats NOT IN (4, 5)) AND (deadline >= current_timestamp))
)
THEN
--UNEXPIRED DEADLINE
RETURN 1;
ELSIF
(
((current_stats NOT IN (4, 5)) AND (deadline < current_timestamp))
)
THEN
--EXPIRED DEADLINE
RETURN 0;
END IF;
```

Is possible create something like that in ElasticSearch to find data using a function?

Example:

```
"bool": {
    "term": [
        {
            function_deadline_ok(deadline, current_stats): 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: A query can execute a [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) in a filter context.

Comment: Thanks @ChinHuang, Script Query was really helpful.